# Matching dataframe rows for finding trade match

Tags: r

I need some help to refactor the script. I have a script which matches the buy and sell trades based on FIFO order.

The initial dataframe looks like this:

> ```
> AsxCode     Order.Type    Trade.Date  Price   Quantity    match_status    match_vol   
> DMP         Buy           17/08/2015  42.1179  105         
> DMP         Sell          26/10/2015  47.05    105         
> RFG         Buy           17/03/2015  7.49     640             
> RFG         Buy           4/06/2015   5.98     870             
> RFG         Buy           29/09/2015  4.2      700         
> RFG         Sell          1/07/2015   5.4286   1510
> ```

Here is the expected output from the script:

> ```
> AsxCode     Order.Type    Trade.Date  Price   Quantity    match_status    match_vol    
> DMP         Buy           17/08/2015  42.1179  105         FULL            105              
> DMP         Sell          26/10/2015  47.05    105         FULL            105  
> RFG         Buy           17/03/2015  7.49     640         FULL            640         
> RFG         Buy           4/06/2015   5.98     870         FULL            870         
> RFG         Buy           29/09/2015  4.2      700         0              4.21          
> RFG         Sell          1/07/2015   5.4286   1510        FULL            1510
> ```

The script has to match the sell trade (indicated by `Order.Type = 'Sell'`) with
the oldest buy. The oldest buy is indicated by `Trade.Date`. If the sell trade finds a buy trade it has to update the `match_status` column and the match_vol column. FULL is used to indicate fully matched and PARTIAL is used to indicate
partially matched. The `match_vol` indicates how many sell units matched with the buy.

Here's the pseudo code for the script:

> ```r
> function(security_code)
> {
>    # for a given security code split into two dataframes
>    # buy_trades and sell_trades
>    buys = df[df$AsxCode==security_code & df$Order.Type=='Buy',]       
>    buy_trades <- buys[order(as.Date(buys$Trade.Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),]
>
>    sells = df[df$AsxCode==security_code & df$Order.Type=='Sell',]
>    sell_trades <- sells[order(sells$Trade.Date),] 
>
>    buy_trades <<- buy_trades 
>    sell_trades <<- sell_trades        
>
>    apply(sell_trades, 1, match_buy_trades) 
>
>    match_buy_trades() 
>    {    
>        for each buy_trades    
>        {
>            next if matched before(i.e buy_trades$match_status == full)
>          if partial match 
>            {      
>              update buy_trades$match_vol
>            update buy_trades$match_status to partial
>            update sell_trades$match_vol
>            update sell_trades$match_status
>         }
>         if full match 
>           {       
>             update buy_trades$match_vol
>           update buy_trades$match_status
>           update sell_trades$match_vol
>           update sell_trades$match_status         
>             break
>         }      
>           if all sell units matched exit  
>    }
> }
> ```

Here is the actual code:

```r
sells = df[df$AsxCode==sec & df$Order.Type=='Sell',]
sell_trades <<- sells[order(sells$Trade.Date),] 

buys = df[df$AsxCode==sec & df$Order.Type=='Buy',]      
buy_trades <<- buys[order(as.Date(buys$Trade.Date)),] 

apply(sell_trades, 1, find_matching_buy)            
result <<- rbind(result, rbind(buy,sell))

find_matching_buy <- function(x){               
    sell_units <- strtoi(x["Quantity"])
    sell_match_units <- strtoi(x["match_vol"])  
    sell_unmatch_units <- sell_units - sell_match_units 

    buy_trades <<- buy_trades[order(buy_trades$Trade.Date),]    
    for(i in 1:nrow(buy_trades)){   
        buy_units <- strtoi(buy_trades[i,"Quantity"])       
        buy_match_units <- strtoi(buy_trades[i,"match_vol"])                
        buy_unmatch_units <- buy_units - buy_match_units        
        buy_status <- buy_trades[i,"match_status"] 


        if (buy_status == "FULL" ) next
        if (sell_unmatch_units == buy_unmatch_units){           
            buy_trades[i,"match_status"] <<- "FULL"
            buy_trades[i,"match_vol"] <<- buy_match_units + sell_unmatch_units                      

            sell_trades[sell_index,"match_vol"] <<- sell_match_units + sell_unmatch_units                   
            sell_trades[sell_index,"match_status"] <<- "FULL"
            break()
        }else if (sell_unmatch_units > buy_unmatch_units){                  
            buy_trades[i,"match_status"] <<- "FULL"
            buy_trades[i,"match_vol"] <<- buy_match_units + buy_unmatch_units           
            sell_trades[sell_index,"match_status"] <<- "Partial"                           
            sell_trades[sell_index,"match_vol"] <<- sell_match_units + buy_unmatch_units                                                
        }else if (sell_unmatch_units < buy_unmatch_units){          
            buy_trades[i,"match_status"] <<- "Partial"
            buy_trades[i,"match_vol"] <<- buy_match_units + sell_unmatch_units          
            sell_trades[sell_index,"match_status"] <<- "FULL"
            break
        }               
        sell_match_units <- strtoi(sell_trades[sell_index,"match_vol"]) # 
        sell_unmatch_units <- sell_units - sell_match_units 
    }       
    # Returning the result
    buy <<- buy_trades
    sell <<- sell_trades
}
```

I don't find the code very modular and structured. The other thing which is nagging me is inside the `find_matching_buy()` how the results are passed through buy and sell dataframe. Also, you can notice that `buy_trades` and `sell_trades` are modified globally.

Comment: Please update your question to include the `dput` of your sample data so we can copy it into R; I tried using `read.table` on the sample data you provided but can't get your code to run without errors.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the expected output for your example data -- shouldn't the matched volume be 0 for the last RFG buy instead of 4.21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few comments on the code:

1. Globally changing values is a pretty big no-no in R code, in large part because it makes functions have unexpected side effects.
2. This code makes use of a lot of for loops instead of using R's vectorized operators.
3. The code separately loops through the buys for each sell, which could be wasteful (why do you need to check a buy again after it has already been matched to a sell?)

Based on this, I have a few proposals:

1. I would do away with the concept of `find_matching_buy` and I would simultaneously match all the buys and sells for a security.
2. When simultaneously matching the buys and sells, I would simplify the logic as follows. Let `b` be the total volume of buys and `s` be the total volume of sells. If `b == s`, then mark everything as fully matching. If `b > s`, then match all sells as fully matching and the first `s` volume of the buys as fully matching. If `s > b`, then match all the buys as fully matching and the first `b` volume of sells as fully matching.

Let's start with a fully reproducible example dataset (I obtained this using `dput`):

```
(dat <- structure(list(AsxCode = c("DMP", "DMP", "RFG", "RFG", "RFG", "RFG"), Order.Type = c("Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Buy", "Buy", "Sell"), Trade.Date = structure(c(16664, 16734, 16511, 16590, 16707, 16617), class = "Date"), Price = c(42.1179, 47.05, 7.49, 5.98, 4.2, 5.4286), Quantity = c(105L, 105L, 640L, 870L, 700L, 1510L)), .Names = c("AsxCode", "Order.Type", "Trade.Date", "Price",  "Quantity"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))
#   AsxCode Order.Type Trade.Date   Price Quantity
# 1     DMP        Buy 2015-08-17 42.1179      105
# 2     DMP       Sell 2015-10-26 47.0500      105
# 3     RFG        Buy 2015-03-17  7.4900      640
# 4     RFG        Buy 2015-06-04  5.9800      870
# 5     RFG        Buy 2015-09-29  4.2000      700
# 6     RFG       Sell 2015-07-01  5.4286     1510
```

The central piece of the code involves determining the matching for sells and buys for a given security, doing away with the concept of `find_matching_buy` using the approach I described above. I'll call this function `match.security`:

```
match.security <- function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$Trade.Date),]
  x$match_status <- "FULL"
  x$match_vol <- x$Quantity
  b <- sum(x$Quantity[x$Order.Type == "Buy"])
  s <- sum(x$Quantity[x$Order.Type == "Sell"])
  if (b > s) {
    # Only some of the buys are matched; update match_status and match_vol for buys
    b.quant <- x$Quantity[x$Order.Type == "Buy"]
    b.vol <- diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(b.quant), s)))
    x$match_vol[x$Order.Type == "Buy"] <- b.vol    
    x$match_status[x$Order.Type == "Buy"] <-
      ifelse(b.vol == b.quant, "FULL", ifelse(b.vol == 0, "0", "Partial"))
  } else if (s > b) {
    # Only some of the sells are matched; update match_status and match_vol for sells
    s.quant <- x$Quantity[x$Order.Type == "Sell"]
    s.vol <- diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(s.quant), b)))
    x$match_vol[x$Order.Type == "Sell"] <- s.vol    
    x$match_status[x$Order.Type == "Sell"] <-
      ifelse(s.vol == s.quant, "FULL", ifelse(s.vol == 0, "0", "Partial"))
  }
  return(x)
}
```

This function first labels everything as fully matched, and then computes the total volume of buys `b` and total volume sells `s`. If `b > s` it goes back and marks the unmatched and partially matched buys (similarly processing sells with `s > b`). The tricky bit is to determine the matched volume for each buy, which we do with `b.vol <- diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(b.quant), s)))`, where `b.quant` is the `Quantity` values for the buys and `s` is the total quantity of sells. For security RFG in the example data above, we have:

```
b.quant <- c(640, 870, 700)
s <- 1510
```

First, we compute the cumulative sum of `b.quant`, which for each buy represents the total quantity of buys if we included all earlier buys and that buy:

```
cumsum(b.quant)
# [1]  640 1510 2210
```

However, we can't match more volume of buys than the volume of sells, so we will cap these values at `s` using the `pmin` function:

```
pmin(cumsum(b.quant), s)
# [1]  640 1510 1510
```

We can see that the differences between these values are the amount of the buy that is actually matched: 640 of the first buy is matched (640-0), 870 of the second buy is matched (1510-640), and none of the third buy is matched (1510-1510). We get this by taking the pairwise differences between elements:

```
diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(b.quant), s)))
# [1] 640 870   0
```

This may seem like a very roundabout/complex way to compute the matched volume for the buys, but in fact it has the nice property that `cumsum`, `pmin`, and `diff` are all vectorized functions in R, so this will actually be much more efficient than a `for` loop when you have a large number of buys and sells for a given security.

We can run our `match.security` function on each of our securities to make sure it is running correctly:

```
match.security(dat[dat$AsxCode == "DMP",])
#   AsxCode Order.Type Trade.Date   Price Quantity match_status match_vol
# 1     DMP        Buy 2015-08-17 42.1179      105         FULL       105
# 2     DMP       Sell 2015-10-26 47.0500      105         FULL       105
match.security(dat[dat$AsxCode == "RFG",])
#   AsxCode Order.Type Trade.Date  Price Quantity match_status match_vol
# 3     RFG        Buy 2015-03-17 7.4900      640         FULL       640
# 4     RFG        Buy 2015-06-04 5.9800      870         FULL       870
# 6     RFG       Sell 2015-07-01 5.4286     1510         FULL      1510
# 5     RFG        Buy 2015-09-29 4.2000      700            0         0
```

The last step is to run `match.security` for each security and to combine the results into a final data frame. To do so, I would use the following:

```
(matched.dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$AsxCode), match.security)))
#       AsxCode Order.Type Trade.Date   Price Quantity match_status match_vol
# DMP.1     DMP        Buy 2015-08-17 42.1179      105         FULL       105
# DMP.2     DMP       Sell 2015-10-26 47.0500      105         FULL       105
# RFG.3     RFG        Buy 2015-03-17  7.4900      640         FULL       640
# RFG.4     RFG        Buy 2015-06-04  5.9800      870         FULL       870
# RFG.6     RFG       Sell 2015-07-01  5.4286     1510         FULL      1510
# RFG.5     RFG        Buy 2015-09-29  4.2000      700            0         0
```

Breaking down this line of code:

- `split(dat, dat$AsxCode)` splits `dat` up into a list of data frames, each associated with one security.
- `lapply(..., match.security)` calls `match.security` on each list element and stores the results of those calls into a list.
- `do.call(rbind, ...)` combines all of our returned lists into a single data frame using `rbind`.

Comment: Hi Josliber, You are very true, the tricky bit is to determine the matched volume for each buy. I have another problem. I was trying to use match.security to also calculate the profit associated with each sell trade.  But could not figure out how to do it ? Please help ? Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner This sounds like a pretty big extension to the code here that probably merits its own question. I would suggest formulating this as a Stack Overflow question, showing what you have done and where you have gotten stuck.